# A nested 'for' loop that returns each day of the month

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want:

```
[1] "January has 31 days"
[1] "February has 29 days"
[1] "March has 31 days"
[1] "April has 30 days"
[1] "May has 31 days"
[1] "June has 30 days"
[1] "July has 31 days"
[1] "August has 31 days"
[1] "September has 30 days"
[1] "October has 31 days"
[1] "November has 30 days"
[1] "December has 31 days"
```

So far I have tried:

```
days <- c("31","29","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31")
months <- c("January", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

for (i in days){
  for (j in months){
      cat(j, "has", i, "days\n")
   }    
}
```

The loop I created returns each j and i 12*12 times which is not correct.

Comment: Your specification says *"February"*, but in the code it is *"Februari"*. Dutch? Swedish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
days <- c("31","29","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31")
months <- c("January", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "September", "October", "November", "December")

for (i in seq_along(days)){ # seq works but as commented seq_along is the better option

    cat(months[i], "has", days[i], "days\n")

  }
```

Also: you are missing *August* in your months vector

PS

As inspired [by U12-Forward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720746/a-nested-for-loop-that-returns-each-day-of-the-month/69720922#69720922), this works as well:

```
invisible(sapply(1:12, function(x) cat(month.name[x], "has", days[x], "days\n")))
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `seq_along()` instead of `seq()`.  In this case they do the same thing, but `seq()` can do just about anything if its argument has a class that defines a method for it, whereas `seq_along` is much simpler.

Comment: you are 100% correct - updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`mapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mapply):

```
> invisible(mapply(function(i, j) cat(j, "has", i, "days\n"), days, months))
January has 31 days
Februari has 29 days
March has 31 days
April has 30 days
May has 31 days
June has 30 days
July has 31 days
August has 31 days
September has 30 days
October has 31 days
November has 30 days
December has 31 days
>
```

---

**Note:** I added `invisible`, so the actual result of `mapply` isn't printed.

---

`mapply` iterates through multiple vectors in parallel.

Comment: @D.J Yeap :) you addressed the OP's original question with a nice answer too :D, I provided an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`stringr::str_glue()` provides a nice alternative. It's vectorised.

```r
library("stringr")

days <- c("31", "29", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July","August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

str_glue("{months} has {days} days")
#> January has 31 days
#> February has 29 days
#> March has 31 days
#> April has 30 days
#> May has 31 days
#> June has 30 days
#> July has 31 days
#> August has 31 days
#> September has 30 days
#> October has 31 days
#> November has 30 days
#> December has 31 days
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is a vectorised operation, so you could do this without loops or `apply` statements.

```
sprintf('%s has %s days', months, days)

# [1] "January has 31 days"   "Februari has 29 days"  "March has 31 days"
# [4] "April has 30 days"     "May has 31 days"       "June has 30 days"
# [7] "July has 31 days"      "August has 31 days"    "September has 30 days"
#[10] "October has 31 days"   "November has 30 days"  "December has 31 days"
```

For display purposes, if you want every statement on a new line -

```
cat(paste0(sprintf('%s has %s days', months, days), collapse = '\n'))

#January has 31 days
#Februari has 29 days
#March has 31 days
#April has 30 days
#May has 31 days
#June has 30 days
#July has 31 days
#August has 31 days
#September has 30 days
#October has 31 days
#November has 30 days
#December has 31 days
```